# Sending a message at a set of fixed times in Python

Tags: python, json, discord, telegram, schedule

Essentially I'm looking for a way to send a countdown message at all of the times added to times.json

I've managed to get the function to send every few seconds, but I want to send it at fixed times

```
@fb.command(name="send")
async def send(ctx, time, countdown, *, message):
    if ctx.author.id == 534473265574314003:
        WAIT_TIME_SECONDS = int(countdown)
        ticker = threading.Event()
        while not ticker.wait(WAIT_TIME_SECONDS):
            await sendMessage(message)
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send("You don't have permission for that command!")
    
@fb.group(name="timer", invoke_without_command=True)
async def timer(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Tr !fb help")

@timer.command(name="add")
async def add(ctx, newtime):
    with open('times.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    addtime = datetime.strptime(newtime, '%H:%M:%S')
    addtime = addtime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    data['times'].append({
            'time':addtime
            })
    with open("times.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what exactly are you trying to do? Send a message at a time specified in the json file? Or a countdown?

Comment: So the times in the json file, will be pre-determined, I would then pull all the times and send a message when each of them hits.

Comment: So, send it daily at the stripped time? I see that you are only storing the time and not days

Comment: If it is daily, you can see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66702487/12451222), let me know if it works

Comment: It would be a countdown, so a message at 1800, 1900 1930, 1945, 1950, 1955, 2000. for example

Comment: ok, so this countdown is invoked by the `times.json` file and not a command?

Comment: Correct, the countdown will pull the times into an array, sort them into the right chronological order, then output the message when each time hits.