# Making a discord.py (rewrite version) timer based off of UTC time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-datetime, pytz

I want to add a timer based off of UTC time to refresh my API files that I download daily. I am using the rewrite version of Discord.py. This is how I made it below:

```
@client.event
# Updates API files daily
async def clock_timer():
    from datetime import datetime
    import pytz

    datetime_utc = datetime.now(pytz.utc)

    await datetime_utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "03:00:00"
    if datetime_utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "03:00:00":
        processes.api_grabber()
```

Am I even doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await datetime_utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == "03:00:00"` is not a valid statement, what you need to do is get the time_delta and sleep till that.

```py
datetime_utc = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
three_am_tmr = datetime_utc.replace(hour=3, minute=0, second=0) + timedelta(days=1)
delta = (three_am_tmr - datetime_utc).total_seconds()
await asyncio.sleep(delta)
#process api here
```

However if you want the timer to execute daily, you have to use a discord.py task or something like [APS](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/)

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(days=1)
async def grab(something):
     #proccess api here


@grab.before_loop()
async def waiter():
   datetime_utc = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
   three_am_tmr = datetime_utc.replace(hour=3, minute=0, second=0) + 
   timedelta(days=1)
   delta = (three_am_tmr - datetime_utc).total_seconds()
   await asyncio.sleep(delta)

#start task in a command
```

### References:

- [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)
- [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

await will "wait" until the event occurs, so the if statement should be useless. If the modules you are importing will *ALWAYS* be used when the program is ran, import them at the top of the file, not inside the function.